# Convert void * to shared_ptr of a type

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

In below code I am trying to convert a void* to a shared_ptr of a type:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class A
{
public:
    A() { l = 0; }
    int l;
    void Show() { std::cout << l << "\n"; }
};

void PrintA(void *aptr)
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a1;
    a1.reset(aptr);
    a1->Show();
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A());
    PrintA(a.get());
}
```

But I get below compilation error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++14 try20.cpp
In file included from C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/memory:82,
                 from try20.cpp:2:
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = void; _Tp = A; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]':
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1023:4:   required from 'void std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::reset(_Tp1*) [with _Tp1 = void; _Tp = A; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
try20.cpp:14:14:   required from here
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:871:39: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'A*' [-fpermissive]
         : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p)
                                       ^
C:/tools/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:874:4: error: static assertion failed: incomplete type
    static_assert( !is_void<_Tp1>::value, "incomplete type" );
```

How can I convert a void pointer to a shared pointer of a type?

Comment: C++ doesn't do implicit `void*` to `non-void*` conversion. And you shouldn't be pinning a new shared pointer in `PrintA` regardless. That `reset` will allocate a completely different state-block. which will leave one of them (the caller) with a dangling pointer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Is this a small example of a larger problem? Are you trying to create a function that will print multiple different classes or something? Why not just pass it as a `shared_ptr` or `A&`?

Comment: Cast back to A* and use [shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: Thanks - yes it is a small example of larger problem. My codebase is spread across C/C++ source code and my flow requires C++ code to C code back to C++ code and I also need to refer back the object instance?

Comment: @Programmer So why do you need a `std::shared_ptr` "back to the object" ? Regarding using shared-from-this as @super suggested,  it would look [something like this](https://pastebin.com/E546Q9k6), but I caution you to consider why you need a shared pointer that deep in the first place, when you already have the object pointer. I can see it if its a thread-lifetime thing, but if not, think about it.

Comment: `shared_ptr` cannot be used to share ownership across a C interface. If you're going to attempt that you'd need to write an instanced API. In the vast majority of cases though you'll do better making a deep copy on the non-owning size of the C interface. I believe that's what should be done here.

Comment: In general you cannot safely convert a regular pointer to a shared pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you cannot change declaration of `PrintA`, your `PrintA` definition should look like:

```
void PrintA(void *aptr)
{
    A* a1 = reinterpret_cast<A*>(aptr);
    a1->Show();
}
```

as you pass to it a pointer.
as you don't reclaim ownership, no need to create `std::shared_ptr`. If you need to share ownership, you have to modify `A` to allow to use `share_from_this`.